# What silver background can I use for jewelry photography?

Tags: jewelry

Does anyone know what background was used on this photo?

https://www.etsy.com/listing/155299103/art-deco-ring-14k-rolled-gold-crystal?ref=shop_home_feat

I tried using a regular silver stock paper, but my photos turned out with too many reflections, almost mirrored. Any ideas on what I can use to achieve this effect?

Many thanks!

Comment: I'd give the dull side of aluminum foil a try...

Answer (score 1):

It looks kind of like it might just be a sand blasted steel table.

Some examples of sand blasted steel that look similar.

[A Table](http://themagazine.info/56/Pictures/Zeus/MiniTavoloInoxThree.jpg), [Another Table](https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/1048157_10151599688782423_1320636271_o.jpg), [A texture photo](http://static8.depositphotos.com/1280399/859/i/950/depositphotos_8597946-Navy-blue-sandblasted-metal-texture-background-to-web-design.jpg), [Watch Band](http://forums.watchuseek.com/attachments/f319/667869d1333256774-fs-20mm-watchadoo-heavy-duty-sand-blasted-steel-bracelet-**sold**-watchadoo2.jpg), [Sheet Metal](http://image.made-in-china.com/2f0j00dvQThtMBCegK/Sandblast-Stainless-Steel-Sheet.jpg)

As far as obtaining something like it, you can either buy a small table or plate or something with the appropriate texture or you could see if you have a local shop that can do sandblasting and have them sandblast a small piece of sheet metal for you to use as a platform.  You might also be able to order a sample swatch from a steel manufacturer, though they might not be interested in sending you one unless they believe you may place a volume order.

Comment: Thank you for your input! I still think it's some kind of paper, though.. In the last photo of that ring you can sort of see some grain to it. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Leona - it is possible to finish steel with a similar texture.  Take a look at http://www.diytrade.com/china/pd/6322711/surface_finish.html for example.  In particular JDC-04 and JDC-08 in image 3 are both similar.  I've seen fine textures very similar to what's in that image on finished steel.  I believe that particular texture is achieved by sand blasting rolled steel.

Comment: you are right, it is very similar! But do I have any options (short of buying a steel table) to achieve this effect?

Comment: @Leona - you might be able to get a small sample piece from a Steel manufacturer.  They typically would have samples and you might be able to talk them in to selling you one.  It might be easier to find a small sandblasted table or plate or something or even see if a local shop can do sandblasting for you and have them sandblast a small sample of sheet metal for you.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at all the pictures, I think you might get similar (even better) results with sand blasted steel. But judging from the scratches on the surface of those pictures they don't look like sharp scratches you would have on metal. It might be some kind of "shiny but grainy" plastic surface. Maybe you can find something similar by looking around a hardware store. You even might get some cheep bits of leftovers from cutting there.

I searched around a bit: You could try asking for adhesive foil in metallic decor and put it onto some cheep underground.

Comment: Thank you! That's a great idea! Will try to look in Home Depot.